# Does the move_base plan a navigation in real time?

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello !
Now I meet a new question . I had a LIDAR on my real car , and the pointclouds of obstacle were showed around the simulate car on the  blank map . When I give a goal `2D navigation` on the blank map , the simulate car and the real car will go to the goal . Now I hope the car can avoid the **obstacles** when going to the goal . The `move_base` will give a navigation to the goal , but it does not  plan a new navigation **in real time** when the car meet new obstacles .

I hope the move_base can plan a navigation in real time .  I am confused about it  !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191103/does-the-move_base-plan-a-navigation-in-real-time-?/) by [Lau](https://answers.ros.org/users/19913/lau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2014-08-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lau](https://answers.ros.org/users/19913/lau/) on 2014-08-24**:
Another question , I input the `PointCloud2` msg which is the **obstacles pointcloud** to the `move_base` . Am I right , or should I input the **original pointcloud** to the `move_base` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are talking about the computer science term "real-time" you should check [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/134551/why-is-ros-not-real-time/).

If you are talking "real-time" meaning "fast enough", it largely depends on your hardware resources and on the parameters you are using in the planning configuration. If this is the case, you can use a faster computer and relax the planning parameters, check [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/73195/navigation-oscilation-on-local-planner/?answer=73255#post-id-73255).

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2014-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lau](https://answers.ros.org/users/19913/lau/) on 2014-08-26**:
My car can not avoid the obstacles but go forward through the obstacles ，I am confused . should I change some config ？

1. List item

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2014-08-26**:
the default move_base planner is not designed to avoid dynamic obstacles.